# Integer and Long conversion

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

Say I want to create a `long` value which has two packed `int`s inside. I want to take my two `int`s and pack them side-by-side within the `long`. I can think of two different ways to achieve this, both of which I believe will work the same way:

```
int a = 0x7FFFFFFF;
int b = 0x10000000;
long x;

// Method one
x = (a & 0xFFFFFFFFL) << 32 | (b & 0xFFFFFFFFL);

// Method two
x = (long) (a << 32) | (long) a;
```

What's the difference between these two methods? Will they both produce the same result in all cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second method does not work. Apart from the typo, (it should end with long b), your `a` will not be affected by the shift (Thanks **harold** for correction). You have to convert before shifting.

```
int a = 0x7FFFFFFF;
int b = 0x10000000;
long x;

// Method one
x = (a & 0xFFFFFFFFL) << 32 | b;

// Method two
x = (((long)a) << 32) | b;
```

Also, in the second and first method, the casting of `b` is redundant. The conversion is done implicitly.

Both methods seem pretty similar. However, method 1 might do some unnecessary operation since it will perform an additional `AND` and conversion.

Method 1:

- al <- a I2L
- res <- al LAND 0xFFFFFFFFL
- res2 <- res LSHL 32
- bl <- b I2L
- al OR bl

Method 2:

- al <- a I2L
- res2 <- al LSHL 32
- bl <- b I2L
- al OR bl

Comment: Yes but `a` didn't overflow in OPs method 2, nothing happens to it. Shift counts are masked.

Comment: @harold I see, I will correct the anwer with your suggestion.